# TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bz2

I am writing a chatbot program with python and when I run my code I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/stephen/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/chatbot.py", line 97, in <module>
    with bz2.open("C:/RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0],timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'
```

Could not find any information online regarding error.  All I saw was maybe that it was a bug and I should report it to python.  Currently running python3.5.3.  This is the part of the code that gets the error.

```
with bz2.open("C:/RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0],timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
    for row in f:
        row_counter += 1
        parent_id = row['parent_id']
        body = format_data(row['body'])
        created_utc = row['created_utc']
        score = row['score']
        comment_id = row['name']
        subreddit = row['subreddit']
        parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)
```

Comment: Please take the moment required to format your question into something readable.

Comment: Just remove the argument `buffering=1000` - are you sure this is the correct signature of the `open` method? Perhaps you want `bz2.BZ2File` instead.

Comment: It seems unlikely you need to report the bug "function doesn't take argument that it's defined not to take" to python.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very explicit:

```
TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'
```

A simple check of the documentation for [`bz2.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#bz2.open) would then show you that this function does not take a `buffering` argument.

So simply remove it.

Answer (score 1):

[The `bz2.open` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html?highlight=bz2#bz2.open) doesn't take a `buffering` argument. Even `bz2.BZ2File`, which takes `buffering`, explicitly notes:

> The `buffering` argument is ignored. Its use is deprecated.

Buffering arguments are a bit nonsensical for compressors; they *have* to buffer to some extent, since if you request X amount of data, they may need need to decompress a block of unknown final size to get it, so they're either decompressing the whole block and buffering the uncompressed data beyond the X request, or stopping decompression when they reach X, buffering the compressed data (and they might still have to buffer some uncompressed data since decompressing a single byte from a stream can produce many bytes of output).

Point is, there is no reasonable way to disable or limit buffering; the needs of the compressor mean you don't have that level of control.